# How to store room database files in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm wondering how to store my database files in Android Studio. I have four different files: SearchHistoryDao, SearchHistoryRepository, SearchHistoryEntry, SearchHistoryViewmodel. How to optimize this, because let's say I would like to create a few more entities, like FavortieLocation and WeatherStatistic which add 8 more files to the project.

Should I package each entity separately?